# killed during installation of torch

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

I am installing the package named `torch` in Ubuntu 18.04 via:

```
python -m pip install torch
```

When the download completes by 99%, the system hangs for some time, and gets the job killed. You can see it in the following image.

[image: package installation progress]

I tried multiple times, but its getting killed every time.

What is the reason behind it? And how can I overcome this issue?

Here's my system information:

[image: system info]

Answer (score 23):

If you are running low on memory you could try with `pip install package --no-cache-dir`